# SWFUpload working fine but not on Windows Server 2012

Tags: flash, deployment, windows-server-2012, swfupload

I have been developing this functionality for **multiple upload using SWFUpload** and *after singnificant R&D* it worked like charms. We even tested and deployed it on **Windows Server 2008 and it worked fine** even there. But now we have to **migrate entire application to Windows Server 2012 and the SWFUpload feature ceased to work**. My research includes following findings:

- My initial reaction was to find some *feature on Windows Server 2012
  that would be somehow related to swf* and I found this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4a178833-1fe0-4cec-81b0-bb8769f0ea03/how-do-i-install-flash-player-in-server-2012)
  telling me to install "**Desktop Experience**" and so I did but it didn't
  help.
- Next I tried to get some other *websites using flash to run on the IE
  on this server machine*. **Some of them ran and some of them didn't**.
- My *last attempt* was to fetch swfupload.swf from another server
  machine (not using Windows Server 2012) while the rest of the
  application still on Win Server 2012 **like the jquery CDN**. This trick
  worked for me fine. But *it is not feasible to use an older server
  just to run one feature*.

So now I need objective answers on following points:

1. Does **SWFUpload really depend on underlying OS** of the server? As I
   think it should only depend on client environment and not of
   server's.
2. Is there **any feature** (other then desktop experience) in **Windows

   Server 2012** that is **directly or indirectly related to Flash**?
3. Has anybody ever programmed something that **used SWF and hosted it
   successfully on Windows Server 2012**?
4. **Any solution or workaround?**

All help is deeply appreciated as asking this question here is my last resort (and hope :) ).

**NOTE: The application is IE specific i.e. doesn't run on other browsers**, so trying them on chrome or firefox is out of the question

Answer (score 0):

This is really a weird issue. What errors do you get on the client-console

**1. Does SWFUpload really depend on underlying OS of the server? As I think it should only depend on client environment and not of server's.**

 Yes you are right. It doesn't depends on the server. It is a javascript library which remains un-executed on the server and is transferred as a static resource attached to the http-response, and gets executed on the browser.

**Is there any feature (other then desktop experience) in Windows
    Server 2012 that is directly or indirectly related to Flash?**
None that I am aware of, even googled it, but no luck.

 
**But there are somethings you can verify.**

1. Please verify that the end-user-operating system is same and has not been tampered with the permissions of browser. (Swfupload uses client side permission such as size of the files you selected, maybe your os doesn't allows this to the browser.)
2. Second thing you can check, check if the library is completely loaded before you are trying to use it.
3. Do use some debugger tool like firebug, and try to execute basic functions of the swfupload library on the client side from the console panel. That way we can make sure, that it has nothing to do with the server-side os or client-side os.

**NOTE: It looks like swfupload is deprecated, you should use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) instead,**